# How to use Wordpress REST API in iOS app?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, alamofire

I need to use WP REST API in my ios app, for now I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
func requestAlamofireToSwiftyJSON(_ url:String, completion: @escaping (JSON?, Bool, Success) -> ()) {

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TIMEOUT
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TIMEOUT

    manager.request(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(value)
            DLog(message:json)

            completion(json, true, .loadOK)

        case .failure(let error):

            DLog(message:"failure")
            DLog(message:"\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")

            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                completion(nil, false, .timeOut)

            } else {
                completion(nil, false, .loadError)
            }             
        }        
    }     
}
```

Logs:

```
{
   "code" : "rest_cannot_access",
   "data" : {
   "status" : 401
    },
 "message" : "Only authenticated users can access the REST API."
}
```

I need to auhentificate me, according to the [WP rest API documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), but I have no idea how to do this in SWIFT.

**EDIT 1**

Almost :)
**Why this code works?**
JSON is displayed in the console.

```
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    let user = "userblablabla"
    let password = "pwdblablabla"

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    Alamofire.request(url, headers:headers).responseJSON{ response in

        DLog(message:url)

        switch response.result {

        case .success:

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(value)
            DLog(message:json)

            completion(json, true, .loadOK)

        case .failure(let error):

            DLog(message:"failure")
            DLog(message:"\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")

            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                completion(nil, false, .timeOut)

            } else {
                completion(nil, false, .loadError)
            }
        }
    }
```

**And why this code doesn't work?**
Error 401 (see above)

```
let headers = [ "Content-Type": "application/json","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest","Cache-Control": "no-cache"]

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TIMEOUT
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TIMEOUT

    manager.request(url).authenticate(user: "userblablabla", password: "pwdblablabla").responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:

            guard let value = response.result.value else {
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(value)
            DLog(message:json)

            completion(json, true, .loadOK)

        case .failure(let error):

            DLog(message:"failure")
            DLog(message:"\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")

            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                completion(nil, false, .timeOut)

            } else {
                completion(nil, false, .loadError)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What endpoint are you trying to access?

Comment: These endpoints : http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/categories, http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/comments

Comment: I've been working on a wordpress -> native iOS application last year. You need to make sure you put in headers with authentication in your request.

Comment: There is a pretty good doc from wordpress here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ where you either for dev purpose could send user and password in header, or use jwt plugin to get a better and more safe authentication. Look here for jwt: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: @JacobAhlberg with my admin login and password ?

Comment: @cmii Yes, but you should not make it visible in your code

Comment: @cmii But if your users can access it, then you should rather take users username and password instead of admin.

Comment: @JacobAhlberg  please see my edit

Comment: @cmii so you tried out my code? Great! I undeleted my answer. So if there is anything else feel free to ask :) Happy coding and vote if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're missing headers with your username and password to access the data. One more thing that I can mention, is to make sure to make it private. Otherwise other users could access the wordpress calls and maybe edit posts and stuff.

```
var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

// Pass in the username and the password in the authorizationHeader
if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: YOURUSERNAME, password: YOURPASSWORD) {
    headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
}

// Request with headers
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        // Handle success
    case .failure(let error):
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need to use Alamofire.SessionManager instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Well @cmii, There are few pointer in API calling, you should consider:

> According to your question you need to pass some request header with user access token. I used the following header in one of my project:

```
headers = [ "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"                    
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Authorization": "bearer " + "KJF73RWHFI23R" ]
```

From the link you shared [wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/). You need to set `X-WP-Nonce` in request header.

```
$.ajax( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1',
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
    },
    data:{
        'title' : 'Hello Moon'
    }
} ).done( function ( response ) {
    console.log( response );
} );
```

Apart from **url**. there are few other parameter in `Alamofire.SessionManager`'s request as:

- **method** - HTTP method(get, post, put, delete etc)
- **parameters** - parameters we wish to send in body
- **encoding** - response encoding
- **headers** - HTTP request headers

You can validate the response status code as `validate(statusCode: 200..<300)`, It will give you success only if response status code lies in range from 200 to 300.

***Your updated code will look like:***

```
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TIMEOUT
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TIMEOUT

        // USE methods, parameters, encoding and headers as per your requirement
        // for example
        // manager.request(url, method: .get, headers: <header dictionary>)

        manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let value = response.result.value else {
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(value)
                DLog(message:json)
                completion(json, true, .loadOK)
            case .failure(let error):
                DLog(message:"failure")
                DLog(message:"\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    //HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
                    completion(nil, false, .timeOut)
                } else {
                    completion(nil, false, .loadError)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using their OAuth plugin (recommanded in the doc), I have now a client key and client secret. How can transform its in token for the header?

Comment: There would be some parameters in which you need to pass both of these. Like `wpApiSettings.nonce` is passed in parameter key - `X-WP-Nonce`

Comment: With your solution + headers with basic Auth, I have this error: Auth request failed with error:
responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(400))